# Checking what plugins a user has installed

Tags: php, firefox

How can you find out what plugins a firefox/chrome user has installed using php? Also is it possible to find out their screen resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifying plugins is possible but kind of messy since the information presented may not be 100% accurate. There are [scripts like Slicer available](http://www.sliceratwork.com/detect-installed-browser-plugins-using-javascript) to do this.

You need to use Javascript to obtain the screen resolution. Some googling turned up [a method](http://www.phpbuddy.com/article.php?id=8) for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for plugins such as IRC, which have a protocol set up for it you can use something like

```
    try {
        window.location = "protocol://etc";
    } catch (e){
        alert("Not supported");
    }
```

Getting the screen resolution with php is impossible, as php is a server side language. You will need to use a client side language for this (such as javascript).

For this you can use

```
screen.width
screen.height
```

With this you can send an ajax request to your server side code to keep track of this if you want!

Edit ::
For something more specific you can look at window.navigator.plugins too (firefox specific) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.plugins)

Answer (score 0):

Quick google search pulled this up.

```
function alertSize() {
   var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
   if(typeof(window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
      //Non-IE
      myWidth = window.innerWidth;
      myHeight = window.innerHeight;
   } else if(document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
      //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
      myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
   } else if(document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
      //IE 4 compatible
      myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
      myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  }
  window.alert( 'Width = ' + myWidth );
  window.alert( 'Height = ' + myHeight );
}
```

Courtesy of http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow

You have to be careful with different browsers this function work pretty well. If you're using jQuery (and probably most other js libraries) there's a function where you could do all that in 1 line and that should be easy to find over google.